# MySQL - Count if generic value between

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my MySQL table:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | startDate           | endDate             |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2018-03-20 10:10:10 | 2018-10-02 21:44:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 2017-08-02 21:44:00 | 2017-08-03 11:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2018-10-25 12:12:12 | 2018-11-25 12:22:33 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 2015-01-01 23:43:27 | 2018-12-29 22:12:35 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------
```

What I like to do is to take last 12 months starting of current month and check for first day of each month how many rows has this day between `startDate` and `endDate`

Expected result (for 18-07-2018):

```
+---------------------+-------+
| date                | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-08-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-11-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2017-12-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-03-01 00:00:00 | 1     | (id 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-04-01 00:00:00 | 2     | (id 1 and 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | 2     | (id 1 and 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | 2     | (id 1 and 4)
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-07-01 00:00:00 | 2     | (id 1 and 4)
+---------------------+-------+
```

Is it possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part is generating the numbers.  The rest is just `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select d.dte, count(t.startdate)
from (select date('2017-08-01') as dte union all
      select date('2017-09-01') as dte union all
      . . . 
      select date('2018-07-01') as dte
     ) d left join
     mysql_table t
     on d.dte >= t.startdate and d.dte <= t.enddate
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

Comment: To pour some sugar all over this, you could write a proc which would also make the 12 month range dynamic, so that window could just be moved as time progresses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . If I wanted to do that, I would use Postgres.  It has such a nice built-in function for that purpose.